Facing lot of prerequisite packages issues while installing perl-LWP-UserAgent package in oracle linux 9
Tried installing perl-LWP-UserAgent using the perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch.rpm package and I got an error message:
$ sudo yum install perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch.rpm

Last metadata expiration check: 0:09:48 ago on Wed 21 Aug 2024 02:14:18 PM UTC.

Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides perl(HTTP::Request) >= 6 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(HTTP::Response) >= 6 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(Authen::NTLM) >= 1.02 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(Data::Dump) >= 1.13 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(File::Listing) >= 6 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(HTTP::Cookies) >= 6 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(HTTP::Date) >= 6 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(HTTP::Negotiate) >= 6 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(HTTP::Request::Common) >= 6 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(HTTP::Status) >= 6.07 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(LWP::MediaTypes) >= 6 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(Net::HTTP) >= 6.18 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(WWW::RobotRules) >= 6 needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(Try::Tiny) needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(HTML::Entities) needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(HTTP::Headers::Util) needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(HTML::HeadParser) needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(Data::Dump::Trace) needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
  - nothing provides perl(HTTP::Config) needed by perl-libwww-perl-6.53-4.el9.noarch from @commandline
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)

If I continue installing one of the package from the above list. It has dependency on some other package and it keeps on going.
Is there any easy way of installing all the packages at ones without installing each package one by one?
I tried to find if there is any master package which can install all of the Perl packages at once but couldn't find any.
Tried installing the packages one by one but it is time consuming and each package has dependency on some other package and it keeps going on.
I tried to use CPAN to install Perl packages, but it stores the installed packages in a different repository that is not accessible via yum commands.

Why the version on the package? What happens if you just run: sudo yum install perl-libwww-perl?

Also, note that you'll need LWP::Protocol::https and its dependencies to make HTTPS requests

I know nothing about Oracle Linux 9, but CentOS Stream 9 repository has this version and yum install perl-libwww-perl works there without a problem.

The CPAN tools will have the same problem. You'd fetch one distribution, cpan will notice its dependencies, and cpan will, recursively, fetch those. That's how it's supposed to work because the code and its dependencies are created and distribution by many independent projects. You'll find the same in Python, npm, and so on.
Can you install a non-versioned package? I wouldn't expect that a stable distribution like LWP to have changed that much that you'd need a specific version of it. And, if you are reaching into the past, you should expect that some things you need aren't available anymore, or the packages it depends on don't want to work with the older package. Everything is designed around installing the latest.
As a side note, a similar project, Mojolicious made the conscious decision to mostly install as a self-contained distribution because of this sort of situation.

try to enable EPEL Repository
sudo yum install epel-release

Then install Dependencies and  perl-libwww-perl
sudo yum install perl-HTTP-Request perl-HTTP-Response perl-Authen-NTLM perl-Data-Dump perl-File-Listing perl-HTTP-Cookies perl-HTTP-Date perl-HTTP-Negotiate perl-HTTP-Request-Common perl-HTTP-Status perl-LWP-MediaTypes perl-Net-HTTP perl-WWW-RobotRules perl-Try-Tiny perl-HTML-Entities perl-HTTP-Headers-Util perl-HTML-HeadParser perl-Data-Dump-Trace perl-HTTP-Config

sudo yum install perl-libwww-perl

